# How to center horizontally and vertically content inside bootstrap 3 row with grids?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I could not find a solution that works for me.

Using Bootstrap 3 I want to make a zig zag content presentation.

I have two bootstrap rows.
First row is divided into two col-sm-6.
First row contains: an iframe with youtube video and div with text in different headers.

Second grid is divided into col-sm-8 and col-sm-4.
Second row contains: div with text in different headers and an image.

The problem is that the content (iframe, text, image) is not centered in the column.

```
 <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <iframe width="100%" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 text-center">
            <h2>What do you need?</h2>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4y810r2/1/)

Ideally I am looking for a solution that only works with bootstrap 3 classes. I have tried col-sm-offset-1, col-sm-offset-2...

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for my site using table html tag which automatically centers the content in a td. For bigger screens I needed to adjust the container height because of the the video embed-responsive class (video container is enlarged if the video is enlarged).

Bootstrap 3 row with columns:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red; height: 100%;">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-responsive-options td-yellow-bg" valign="middle" align="center">
                        <h2>What do you need?</h2>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue; height: 100%;">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-responsive-options td-gray-bg" valign="middle" align="center">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Responsive height:

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {
        .container {
            height: 600px;
        }

        .td-responsive-options {
            height:600px;
        }
    }
```

You can find a working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcx20zdv/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to offset by 3 so it is in the middle. (12-columns) - (6-columns) = 6-remaining-columns. So, divide that in half for 3-columns on each side. I also threw in a bootstrap responsive embed so it displays nicer at different screen sizes.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
    <h2>What do you need?</h2>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This centers all content vertically. I want to center iframe horizontally and vertically in the column and the content centered in the other column. This is the [result](https://imgur.com/a/CMOu2vk) of the code provided by you.

Comment: Oh, I only saw the horizontal centering, so I thought you were trying to stack them. Unfortunately with Bootstrap 3, the columns aren't the same height because they use float styles instead of flex styles. I'll try to post some html css without Bootstrap to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 3 uses a float-based grid, there isn't a way to make it's columns the same height unless you use javascript. However, you can mock up something like what you want with vanilla html & css:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="split-centered-section">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div>
                    <h2>What do you need?</h2>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.bg-grey {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

.split-centered-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0 -15px; /* negate the padding on the col-sm-12  but allows for padding below to match */
}
.split-centered-section .column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment */
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tested your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbuy0g9k/). The video is not displayed. Although I found a solution, I think that your answer is simpler. Could you please provide a working fiddle so I can mark your response as the correct one?